# How to animate navigation bar with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a navigation bar see my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dfbwp71u/
when I uses `css()` its working properly but when I use `animate()` its not giving me the result.

my html:

```
  <nav class="navigation navbar-fixed-top">

  </nav>
```

jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
 // these conditional statements are working fine
if($(window).scrollTop() > 5)
{
  $('.navigation').css({
    'background-color':'#000'
  });
}
else
{ 
  $('.navigation').css({
    'background-color':'#eee'
  });
}

});
```

When I replace the `.css()` to `animate()` it stops giving me the result.

```
   // ???
  $('.navigation').animate({
    'background-color':'#000'
  });
```

Comment: for that you have to use jquery ui too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't need `animate` for this unless you are not satisfied with `css` `transition`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dfbwp71u/2/)**

What I would do is just add a `class` called `fixed` and assign `background-color`:`#000` like one below:

```
.fixed{
     background-color:#000
}
```

and then I'll toggle this `class` based on the condition as below:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 5)
  {
    $('.navigation').addClass('fixed');
  }
  else
  { 
    $('.navigation').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

The main thing we need to add here is `transition` property to `.navigation` and it will take care of rest:

```
.navigation
{
    min-height:100px;
    max-width:100%;
    background-color:#eee;
    transition: background 500ms;//change time accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   jQuery.Color plugin is used)

so either use **jquery-ui** or  **jQuery.Color** plugin

Answer (score -1):

Add Jquery UI if you not add and change css property name 'background-color' to 'backgroundColor',

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 5)
{
  $('.navigation').animate({backgroundColor:'#eee'});
}
else
{ 
  $('.navigation').animate({backgroundColor:'#000'});
}
});
```